# How to Initialise 2D char array after being declared in header

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array, compiler-errors, syntax-error

I'm working on a project at the moment that requires the reading of individual characters from a 2D array to determine the content in the corresponding grid.

I'm declaring the 2D character arrays as follows:

```
class GridManager{
    static char level1[5][6];
    static char level2[5][6];
    static char level3[6][10];
};
```

and I'm initiliasing them in the cpp file as follows:

```
char GridManager::level1[5][6] =
{{'O','P','T','T','E','N'},
    {'W','M','N','W','M','P'},
    {'M','T','P','M','P','R'},
    {'O','N','M','P','M','R'},
    {'L','E','E','E','E','N'}};
char GridManager::level2[5][6] = 
{{'O','E','E','E','T','P'},
    {'W','M','B','K','W','R'},
    {'L','B','P','B','M','R'},
    {'M','P','N','T','E','N'},
    {'L','N','B','B','B','R'}};
char GridManager::level3[6][10]= 
{{'O','T','T','T','T','T','T','T','P','R'}
 {'O','T','T','T','T','B','P','R','R','R'}
 {'L','O','T','T','P','P','N','R','P','R'}
 {'W','W','T','L','K','K','K','K','R','R'}
 {'W','W','R','K','T','E','E','O','P','R'}
 {'W','B','N','N','B','B','B','N','B','N'}};
```

However it keeps throwing up an error on the first { on the second row saying it was expecting a }.
I have tried initialising them as static in the .cpp file as well but this doesn't make a difference. 
Any and all help would be appreciated.
If you need more info/code please don't hesitate to ask
Regards,
AzKai

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to place commas in the definition

```
char GridManager::level3[6][10]= 
{{'O','T','T','T','T','T','T','T','P','R'}
 {'O','T','T','T','T','B','P','R','R','R'}
 {'L','O','T','T','P','P','N','R','P','R'}
 {'W','W','T','L','K','K','K','K','R','R'}
 {'W','W','R','K','T','E','E','O','P','R'}
 {'W','B','N','N','B','B','B','N','B','N'}};
```

Shall be

```
char GridManager::level3[6][10]= 
{{'O','T','T','T','T','T','T','T','P','R'},
 {'O','T','T','T','T','B','P','R','R','R'},
 {'L','O','T','T','P','P','N','R','P','R'},
 {'W','W','T','L','K','K','K','K','R','R'},
 {'W','W','R','K','T','E','E','O','P','R'},
 {'W','B','N','N','B','B','B','N','B','N'}};
```

Comment: I made this change at the start. It was still throwing up the error in all three arrays. I had to restart visual studio after several cleans and rebuilds it's now miraculously working. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

This looks ok, but you are missing commas in the definition of your last array, as follows:

```
char GridManager::level3[6][10]= 
{{'O','T','T','T','T','T','T','T','P','R'}, // <-
 {'O','T','T','T','T','B','P','R','R','R'}, // <-
 {'L','O','T','T','P','P','N','R','P','R'}, // <- HERE
 {'W','W','T','L','K','K','K','K','R','R'}, // <-
 {'W','W','R','K','T','E','E','O','P','R'}, // <-
 {'W','B','N','N','B','B','B','N','B','N'}};
```

Comment: You are most absolutely right. I forgot to add them by accident but this error comes up in all 3 arrays.

Comment: Damn! Which platform and compiler version are you using ? Can you please also post the compiler diagnostic output ? This all works fine for me (XCode / apple llvm 5.0)

Comment: I'm using visual studio 2010 with x32 debugger. I'm not sure which window that's in